# Hibernate Unknow Entity Exception after Spring/Hibernate Upgrade

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I did Spring upgrade from 3.x to 5.x and even Hibernate i got it upgraded to 5.x. Previously i was able to execute all the nativequeries using Hibernate JPA, but now the same piece of code is not working especially component-scan annotation (not instantiating beans anymore) after upgrade.

Below are the code snippets.

In Application context:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.flight.nh.domain" />
```

Bean class in com.flight.nh.domain package.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NOTIFICATION_ROLE")
public class NotificationRole implements Serializable {

}
```

Piece of code were below exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.baxter.renal.nh.domain.NotificationRole
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:670) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.14.Final.jar:?]
```

```
Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(nativeSql.toString(), NotificationRole.class);
        query.setParameter(INITIAL_VERSION, INITIAL_VERSION_VAL);
        query.setParameter(USER_ID, userId);
        query.setParameter(ROLE_LIST, roleIdList);
```

```
    return query.getResultList();
```

Looks like NotificationRole bean could not be instantiated by spring leading to the exception as component-scan is not working as expected.

The same piece of code used to work with Spring 3.x. Can anyone please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: tried to scan the parent package of the NotificationRole entity ?
just for test then detect if hibernate changed the way they scan packages of it is another issue.

Comment: @AnasAltarazi, scan till parent package didn't work.

Comment: @James Z , I think it is easier to migrate to spring boot instead of fixing spring framework compatibility issues.

Comment: Overall the webapp is portlet based. So, cannot convert to spring boot.